# redirecting HTTP urls to HTTPS pages

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone  help me with this?

I manages to redirect already the root access. when someone  access my site using sample.com it will redirect in to https://sample.com/ but when someone access the site using this method , sample.com/blog, It still loads the http://sample.com/blog not the https://it should be

Comment: whats the rule in htaccess you have put ?

Comment: this one                                                                                       RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: it works when someone access my site like this      sample.com it will redirected to https://sample.com/   but when something is added like this one sample.com/blog , it will still use the http:// protocol

Comment: Does `/blog/` also have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked on most of my projects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

The following is inside a `.htaccess` placed in the root HTML folder of the website. Place additional rewrite rules *after* this rule.

EDIT: this `RewriteCond` expects HTTP to run on the standard port 80. Adjust it in case you transfer HTTP over some other port.